# Ubuntu 18.04 Proceesor system requirement

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu

Can I install ubuntu 18.04 in my intel pentium quad core processor laptop?
All other system requirement have met already but I am confused on this point.

Comment: This is why Ubuntu's install .iso has a "Try Ubuntu" feature - so you can test Ubuntu on your hardware without commitment, and without wiping the existing OS. Judge for yourself if it works well.

Comment: You haven't said what type/class of pentium cpu you're talking about.  For example my box uses a c2q-q9400 and it works perfectly.  You've also tagged virtualbox, which means the host OS, plus version of virtualbox (and architecture of both) have a lot of influence if you're wanting to use it in vm only.